# Moving information from a sidebar to a cursor location

Tags: google-docs-api

I am very new to coding and trying to learn.  I created a google sidebar in google docs and am trying to figure out how to send a response from a radio button in the sidebar to the cursor in the google doc.  I know that probably is simple but I am very much stuck and no matter where I look I get I see examples for sheets but keep getting stuck in the doc form...any help would be awesome!!

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow! Can you show us what you're already tried, please?

Comment: <hr attribute1=".." attribute2="..">
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title><center>21st Century Themes</center></title>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("input[type='button']").click(function(){
            var radioValue = $("input[name='gender']:checked").val();
            if(radioValue){
                alert(radioValue);
            }
        });
        
    });

Comment: </script>
</head> 
<body>
    <p><center><b>21st Centry Themes</b></center></p>
    <p> 
        <label><input type="radio" name="gender" value="Global Awareness">Global Awareness</label> 
        <label><input type="radio" name="gender" value="Financial, economic, business...">Financial, economic, business...</label>
    </p>
    <center><p><input type="button" value="Get Value"></p></center>

Comment: The second set I posted allows me to send it to an alert box but not to my doc...

Comment: Instead of posting in the comments, can you [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/54887581/edit) your question to include your code, so it will be easier for people to analyze?